# REST Downloading a document Response Headers don't have Content-Length

Tags: rest-api, document

I am using /Document/{id}/Body endpoint to download the file.

The returned response headers don't contain a content-length header { which really is a norm, right ? } ...

Does anyone know why that is the case ? Any other work around ?

Answer (score 3):

Content-Length is not required if the response uses a chunked transfer encoding. One possible work around would be to use a HTTP/1.0 request rather than 1.1 as i think chunked transfer is not a part of 1.0. But really you shouldn't be relying on the header, what do you need it for?

Comment: `res.responseBody.size()` should suffice, though, shouldn't it?

Comment: depends on what you're using to make the request.